# Boundary conditions of a heat PDE

Tags: thermodynamics, boundary-conditions, differential-equations, thermal-conductivity

I have recently read a paper on heating a metal bar. The heat equation is used to analyze the system but as I can't find the right boundary conditions used to solve the heat equation. I'm hoping that by explaining the experiment here someone could point out what I'm missing.

A metal rod (of length $L$) is held at a constant temperature $T=T_0$ at the $x=L$. At the end $x=0$ heat is generated that results in a constant heat flux of $\vec{q}=\frac{\dot{Q}}{A}$.

Solving the equation for the initial conditions, they get that $T(x,0)=T_0+(l-x)\frac{\dot{Q}}{AK}$.

I've been able to follow the paper this far where I get:

\begin{array}{lkl}
\frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial x^2} = \frac{1}{D}\frac{\partial T}{\partial t} & \textrm{Heat equation} \\
T(L,t)=T_0 & \textrm{Boundary condition} \\
T(x,0)=T_0+(L-x)\frac{\dot{Q}}{KA} & \textrm{Initial condition}
\end{array}

I only know how to solve PDEs with the variable separation method and I don't see how I could apply it here. I feel like I'd need another boundary condition.

As the temperature at $x=0$ is dependent on a function of time, I could use $T(0,t)=f(t)$ as the boundary condition I'm missing leaving the PDE as something like this:

\begin{array}{lkl}
\frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial x^2} = \frac{1}{D}\frac{\partial T}{\partial t} & \textrm{Heat equation} \\
T(L,t)=T_0, T(0,t)=f(t) & \textrm{Boundary condition} \\
T(x,0)=T_0+(L-x)\frac{\dot{Q}}{KA} & \textrm{Initial condition}
\end{array}

Now, I feel like there should be a relation between $f(t)$ and the heat flux at point $x=0$ but I don't know how to get the exact relation in order to get the last boundary condition.

I'm not looking for a solution as I'd like to get it myself but I don't even know where to start or where to get that extra boundary condition.

Thanks for the help and sorry for any spelling or grammar mistakes I might have made as english is not my first language

Comment: You should take a closer look at your problem statement. The $x=0$ boundary is  *not* time-dependent, but is *spatially* dependent.

Comment: It looks like they are solving for the steady state solution.

Comment: What do you mean by "solving for the initial conditions"? Usually one is given the initial conditions. The equation you give is actually the equilibrium or steady-state solution. The heat equation is then satisfied because $\frac{d^2T}{dx^2}=\frac{dT}{dt}=0$, as one can easily verify. If that's also the initial conditions, then the system never evolves; it's already at steady state. Please clarify.

Comment: @Chemomechanics, and how can I find the inital conditions? Is it possible to get them from the steady state solution?

Comment: Is the initial condition T= To?

Comment: @ChetMiller, for what I understand from the paper, they take the time $t=0$ when the heat source is removed. Therefore shouldn't the initial condition be the steady state condition?

Comment: Ah, so why didn’t separation of variables work?

Comment: The bc after t =0 is dT/dx =0 at x=0

Comment: @ChetMiller, and why would $dT/dx=0$ be the bc at $x=0$?I don't really have a good intuition on what the space derivatives physically mean on the heat equation

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140836/discussion-between-mikel-solaguren-and-chet-miller).

Answer (score 0):

Your boundary condition at $x=0$ is simply a von Neumann boundary condition. Using conservation of energy:
$$
q=-\lambda\partial_xT(x=0,t)
$$
with $\lambda$ the heat conductivity and the rhs being Fourier’s law. I am using a small slab at the extremity, and can make the varying internal energy (proportional to the width) vanishingly small, so no time derivative term.

For your problem, it’s best to solve for the steady solution first, then find the modes for the homogenous boundary conditions. With these, reconstruct the temporal initial condition.

Hope this helps.